# How to read other button id, avoid all go to first button

Tags: java, android

I want do after click the button, that button will become red and disable, and other button will also disable, this one i already successfully done, but the problem is, for example, i choose any button, it show me the button selected is become red, but when i reopen the application, the first button become red, i mean for example i choose button 5, in that page, it still show me, all button disable and button 5 will become red means i choose that button, but when i reopen again, the first button become red, same as choose button2, button3 and button4 and the below code i find the problem at there, it only just can read first button id, i used shared preferences. Who know the answer, kindly help me, tq, if can please show me the code.

```
   if(getColor() != getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)) {

       if(button7.isClickable()) {

            button7.setBackgroundColor(getColor());
            button7.setEnabled(false);
            button8.setEnabled(false);
            button9.setEnabled(false);
            button10.setEnabled(false);
            button11.setEnabled(false);
        }else if(button8.isClickable()) {

            button8.setBackgroundColor(getColor());
            button7.setEnabled(false);
            button8.setEnabled(false);
            button9.setEnabled(false);
            button10.setEnabled(false);
            button11.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pl simply the question text, it is confusing

Comment: I dont think anyone will take the work of reading all of that

Comment: I don't think that the problem is here, post more of your code, like where do you use the shared preferences and how.

Comment: private void storeColor(int color){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putInt("color", color);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

Comment: private int getColor(){
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ButtonColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int selectedColor = mSharedPreferences.getInt("color", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        return  selectedColor;
    }

Comment: @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        button11.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
    
                        storeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));

                         button7.setEnabled(false);
                        button8.setEnabled(false);

Comment: for onclick i use dialog , mean each button has dialog ,in the dialog has three button, i show select button code

Comment: hope has anyone can help me, thanks..., urgent